How to reset, to its alternative form, a previously quoted acronym, while retaining the general initialization for a new acronym?
In my thesis, I'm using the acro package to introduce characters.
At the first occurrence, I broadcast the long form (in the example FirstName1 Name1 (Birth1-Death1)) then after the short form (Name1).
For my chapters to be self-contained, all characters already mentioned in previous chapters would have to be reset to the alternative form (FirstName1 Name1). But all new characters must be quoted in long form first, as usual.
Here's the code I'm using but which doesn't work with the acbarrier command (I've forced what I'd like to have in chapter 3) :
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{barriers/use=true, barriers/reset=true}

\DeclareAcronym{1}{short=Name1, long=FirstName1 Name1 (Birth1-Death1), alt =FirstName1 Name1, tag=perso, first-style=long}
\DeclareAcronym{2}{short=Name2, long=FirstName2 Name2 (Birth2-Death2), alt =FirstName2 Name2, tag=perso, first-style=long}
\DeclareAcronym{3}{short=Name3, long=FirstName3 Name3 (Birth3-Death3), alt =FirstName3 Name3, tag=perso, first-style=long}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\ac{1} ... \ac{1}.

\acbarrier \chapter{Chapter 2}
\ac{1} ... \ac{2}.

\acbarrier \chapter{Chapter 3}
\aca{1} ... \ac{3}.

\end{document}

Does anyone have an idea how to solve my problem?
Thanks a lot!
